# Finding the runtime of a task by name

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

Can this query be improved? I iterate over a couple of thousand times, and if I can improve it, it should decrease the run time.  Otherwise I might look into using a batch instead of doing one at a time. I'm using MS SQL 11.

```
job
****
id
name


job_stats
*************
id
job_id
median_runtime

select js.median_runtime from job_stats js 
      join job j 
      on j.id = js.job_id 
      where j.name = '%s'
```

Comment: The issue is not so much with the query, but with the code that uses this query. If you are executing this query in a loop "a couple of thousand times", then _that_ is a huge cause for concern. I strongly recommend that you post a separate question to review that looping query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a query this simple, it's going to be hard to make any major improvements.

Firstly, you should use `INNER JOIN` as opposed to `JOIN` it makes the query much easier to understand at a glance.

I would argue that you don't need to alias `job_stats` or `job`, they are both already fairly short and are much more meaningful names than `J` and `JS`

You should use consistent indentation and you SQL is typically written with all the keywords in uppercase like this:

```
SELECT job_stats.median_runtime
FROM job_stats
INNER JOIN job
    ON job.id = job_stats.id
WHERE job.name = '%s'
```

Lastly, is the final statement supposed to be this:

```
WHERE job.name LIKE '%s'
```

or is it correct as is, I can not tell.

Comment: Yes its correct b/c I'm using it in script and iterating the name from the list for each time.

Comment: @user3590149 I thought it might be, I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

Whether this simple query is optimal or not will come down to the indexes on the tables involved. In particular:

- Make sure the fields used in the `join` are indexed: `job_stats.job_id` and `job.id`
- Make sure the fields used in the `where` condition are indexed: `job.name`

If that's already the case, then the query is optimal,
but I also recommend to use the writing style suggested by [PenutReaper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50242/penutreaper).